# CoffeeScript --compile order in sub-directories

Tags: coffeescript

Is there any way to define CoffeeScript compilation order in sub-directories?
Please consider the following example:

Files:

- src/App.coffee
- src/view/B.coffee
- src/view/a/A.coffee

Where class A extends B.

```
coffee --join js/app.js --compile src/view/ src/App.coffee
```

This throws an error in the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

If I rename folder **a** to **z**, the error is gone and everything works fine.

- src/view/**z**/A.coffee

I would expect the compiler to read all .coffee files from src/view/ before it goes into src/view/ sub-directories. Again, is there any way to do that?

**Edit:**
PC Windows 7,
CoffeeScript version 1.3.3

Comment: This is a result of standard *nix behavior, where everything is listed alphabetically including folders. Try `--compile src/view/B.coffee src/view/a/ src/App.coffee` ?

Comment: Works only if I add all src/view/[.coffee] files then all src/view/[folders]. Doesn't work with generic src/view/

Comment: `--compile src/view/*.coffee src/view/a/ src/App.coffee` worked for me

Comment: It does work in this example. What if there are more folders inside src/view ? Then it would only work if the compile line contained ALL of these folders. I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: well, it can't make guesses for you.. you need to either name it alphabetically, pass the list arguments or use a build script.

Comment: My interest is in a way to give priority to folder hierarchy over alphabetic order during compilation, but apparently there isn't. I just renamed my files, it's not ideal but works.

Answer (score 5):

The only solution I think is to create the compile order manually within a build script.
You would create an ordered collection with filenames, where as the loop iterates and concatenates a new big string, which can be compiled as one file.

Create a Cakefile with following content, check Syntax first. And run with `cake build`. That should work, cake comes with CoffeeScript.

```
fs = require 'fs'
{exec} = require 'child_process'

viewsDir = "src/view"
coffeeFiles = [
  'B'
  'A'
]

task 'build'
  # loops through coffeeFiles. 
  for file, index in coffeeFiles then do (file, index) ->
    fs.readFile "#{viewsDir}/#{file}", 'utf8', (err, content) ->
      appCoffee[index] = content
      compile() if --remaining is 0

  compile = ->
    fs.writeFile 'js/app.coffee', appCoffee.join('\n\n'), 'utf8', (err)   ->
      throw err if err
      exec 'coffee --compile js/app.coffee', (err, stdout, stderr) ->
        throw err if err
          console.log stdout + stderr

          # you can skip deleting the app.coffee file
          fs.unlink 'js/app.coffee', (err) ->
            throw err if err
            console.log 'Created app.coffe, compiled to app.js and removes app.coffee'

            # maybe additional taks 
            # invoke 'test'
```

Documented also in Wiki of Coffeescript [https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/[HowTo]-Compiling-and-Setting-Up-Build-Tools](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/%5BHowTo%5D-Compiling-and-Setting-Up-Build-Tools)

Before first loop you could also make it loop through different directories. And just list filenames in coffeeFiles to be processed before the others not in listed and the rest could be added to list with fs.readDir().

Answer (score 2):

We created a simple module to solve a similar problem:

https://github.com/Vizir/rehab

Just put `#_require [filename].coffee` on your file and you're done.

We are using it in productions with complex dependency graphs.